# Remove the whole menu in the admin

Tags: admin, menus

How can i remove the whole menu in the admin?

I have this code:

```
function remove_menu_items() {
    global $menu;

    end( $menu );

    while ( prev($menu) ) {
        $value = explode( ' ', $menu[ key($menu) ][0] );
        if ( $value[0] != NULL ? $value[0] : "" ) {
            unset( $menu[ key($menu) ] );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menu_items' );
```

This only removes the default menu items, any pages added to the menu by a plugin are still there.

How can i remove the whole menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
add_action('admin_head', 't5_hide_menu');
function t5_hide_menu()
{
    $GLOBALS['menu'] = array();
    ?>
<style>#adminmenuback,#adminmenuwrap{display:none !important}
#wpcontent, #footer{margin-left:0 !important}</style>
<?php
}
```

Now I want to know: *why?* :)

Comment: +1 for _"Now I want to know: why? :)"_ Btw: (not sure) Isn't the `adminmenu` or `admin_menu` (or even `_admin_menu`) hook more appropriate for this?

Comment: @kaiser I like it when my `style` elements are placed in the `<head>`. Therefore it’s `admin_head`.

Comment: _Note to later readers:_ This (empty array) is the only solution that will successfully prevent an error if plugins add pages later on. @toscho If you dump the global at for e.g. `admin_footer`, I guess there'll be left overs from plugins that hook later. Imho would be better to split this into two functions and go into `adminmenu` with a really high priority.

Comment: It's very important to note that hiding the menu won't prevent users from accessing the pages directly if they know the URI. Otherwise it's just [an illusion, like an aztec tomb](http://www.hulu.com/watch/1328/arrested-development-meet-the-bluths?c=69:85).

Comment: thanks I should have said i dont want to do it using css or javascript.

I want to do this as I am styling the admin and using my own menu.

Comment: @Lee Some markup is hard coded. You have to use CSS – or output buffering.

Comment: ok thanks i dont mind doing it if the bar is still there but at the moment i can't rmeove all the menu items

Comment: Then just use the part `$GLOBALS['menu'] = array();`. You can fill the array with new values and they will be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS:

```
#adminmenuwrap { display:none; }
```

---

Or you could use Javascript and hide each element.

Target #menu-media, #menu-links and so on.

---

Or you could do this:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'i_can_haz_no_menuz' );
function i_can_haz_no_menuz() {
    global $menu;
    $menu = array();
}
```

Just remember that other plugins may add menus after this point.

Comment: +1 But are you shure you don't get an error when setting it to `null`?

Comment: thanks I should have said i dont want to do it using css or javascript.

I tried you code and it didnt remove the pages added by plugins. It might be that i need to use another hook

Comment: I tried:

function remove_menu_items() {
global $menu;
$menu = null;

}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menu_items', 12);

But i got errors

Comment: probably should be an array instead of null

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to remove the entire thing:

```
global $menu;
unset($menu);
```

Hope this helps!

Btw, the admin menu code is in /wp-admin/menu.php if you want to look at it and mess with certain items.

Comment: +1 But I guess it will throw an error if some plugin tries to add stuff to a non existing array.

Comment: this doesnt work

Comment: You're supposed to put that code in a function which is hooked to admin_head. ie. `function noMenu() { global $menu; unset($menu); }` 
and then
`add_action('admin_head', 'noMenu');`

Comment: yes i did that thanks but ended up with lots of errors